# Ephemeral Port Conversation Partner resolution

Tags: networking, port, traffic

I am currently investigation network traffic. In here, i want to find out which client talks to which server. Obviously, I can have a look at the first packet and see:

```
PartyA:38531 ===request===> PartyB:80
PartyB:80    ===response==> PartyA:38531
PartyA:38531 ===request===> PartyB:80
PartyB:80    ===response==> PartyA:38531
PartyA:38531 ===request===> PartyB:80
PartyB:80    ===response==> PartyA:38531
```

So PartyA requests something from a webserver (PartyB).
The Port of PartyA is randomly chosen (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port).
But what if the packet capturing did not capture the first packet? So the first packet would be:

```
PartyB:80    ===response==> PartyA:38531
                  ....
```

How am I able to find out who the server is, and who the client? Are there rules like e.g. "The ephemeral port has to be higher than the static port" or something like this? But then, what would happen with a port higher than 61000?

I want to analyse the traffic going to a certain server and coming from a certain host. But what if a new connection comes up with a new ephemeral port? Are there approaches to find out who the server is and who the client?

Hope that my question is clear :)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

It all depends, ephemeral ports are ephemeral on machine which allocated them, they can be out of ephemeral pool on the other system, or on the other kernel, so you should not expect too much from them.

The only thing you can be 99% sure, that ports in range `49151–65535 (2^15+2^14-1 to 2^16−1)` are ephemeral, but they are not restricted to use by server (even more, they are *suggested for private use*).

Better concentrate on static port. If you have few active connections to the same port from different addresses, may it be static port on server and different ports on different addresses - ephemeral ports on clients?

If there is only one session between client and server, it doesn't matter who is a server and who is a client, you can only retrieve this from the protocol they use.

Comment: "_If there is only one session between client and server, it doesn't matter who is a server and who is a client..._" Exactly. TCP doesn't even have a client/server concept. It is a connection between peers. Client/server is an application-layer concept.

Comment: As I have big traffic files, I found out, that I could also just look for 0x2 tcp flags (SYN) and record all ports used in the establishment of a connection. Afterwards, I have a list of "service" ports. Furthermore, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271660/big-graph-in-memory/37272260 is able to generate a list of most common ports while deleting ephemeral ports.