# Big graph in memory

Tags: python, numpy, memory, port

I want to record all used ports within huge pcaps. There are 65535 ports available, and each port is able to talk each other port:
65535 x 65535 links in total

The matrix will be very sparse (many 0 entries).
Additionally, I think the edges don't have to be directed, so Port1->Port2 may be added to Port2->Port1 (which reduces our amount of values to 65535 * 65536 / 2).
How would you store this using python? In numpy? What will be the estimated amount of memory consumption for this?

Afterwards, I want to find the greatest sum for one port and pop() it (the whole row and column while). This means, i want to find e.g. that Port1 was used 500 times (100 times from Port2 to Port1, 300 times from Port3 to Port1, Port4 to Port1 100times)...

Graphically spoken, I want to have 65535 nodes that could be connected with each other. Then I want to find the node that has the highest sum of values on connected edges. Afterwards, I want to pop the node (and delete the corresponding edges, which will decrease the sum of other nodes).

Thanks!

Comment: You want, you want, you want... Nobody cares what I want! :P - It is required a bit of your effort (aka codes) to pretend an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, and depending on how sparse is sparse, a dict-of-dicts will handle this quite well.

```
connections = { ..., 8080: { 4545:17, 20151:3, ...}, ...}
```

If I have understood what you are doing correctly, then the count of connections to port p is

```
count = sum( connections[8080].values() )
```

removing port p is

```
del connections[p]
for conn in connections.values():  # edit, bug fixed.
    if p in conn: 
         del conn[p]
```

If you want to try to save memory by storing only half the pairs, then simplicity suffers greatly.

Comment: This is good. Thank you very much! One could also create a new array and save all "deleted" ports, so even if new packets arrive, one is able to use the old list for further analysis.

Comment: Another way might be a list of sets for determining presence in or absence from the sparse data, and a dict indexed by an integer 2-tuple for storing the sparse data (which need never be deleted, could be continuously updated, and one could map `(m,n)` to `(n,m)` if `n>m`, to avoid redundant storage of non-directed edges.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the adjacency list representation of Graph, it will most probably suits your needs.

However, a graph containing 65535 vertices is not that big. Even if you cannot represent it with a simple matrix.

The memory consumption is O(E+V) with V number of vertices (65535) and E number of edges (on a sparse graph, it has the same magnitude order than V).

Comment: 65536 nodes => 65535*65535 edges possible, which equals 4294967296 edges (or entries in a matrix). if each entry consumes 4 byte e.g. this would be 16GB

Comment: If it is sparse (few edges by vertex), it is not.

Comment: for most vertices it will be sparse, for ports used for certain protocols (like 6000 for x11) it won't be sparse...

Comment: Sparsity (or rather density) is defined for a graph, not for a few specific vertices. There are only a few ports (regarding the 65535 available) which are widely used. Even if all the vertices had 100 edges each, the graph would be sparse (density ~ 0.0015).

Comment: Widely used, yes. But the opposite site uses a epheremal port (which is randomly in a range). Therefore, ports 65536/2 to 61000 are used often, in default linux machines :/

Comment: Have you checked adjacency list like indicated ? The actual numbers of ports dont matter in this implementation, you simply can store 100 links per node regardless of how they are placed in the 'map'.